# changing width of div to match width of span tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my first post here. I have been searching through questions previously posted that sound similar to what I am encountering I've tried those answers and still haven't made it work yet.

I got the following code. Somewhat similar to what I'm working on.

CSS:

```
.ContentTable {
    width:100%;
    heigth:100%;
    empty-cells:show;
}

.WidthLimited{
    overflow:scroll;
    overflow-x:auto;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}

.ResultListContainer{
    width:95%;
    color:black;    
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="Wrapper">
    <div id="Content1"><div/> 
    <span id"SearchControl">
        <table class="ContentTable">
            <tbody>
                <tr id="Title">Title here</tr>              
                <tr id="Body">
                    <td>Some text 1</td>
                    <td>Some text 2</td>
                    <td>Some text 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="Body">
                    <td>Some text 1</td>
                    <td>Some text 2</td>
                    <td>Some text 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="Body">
                    <td>Some text 1</td>
                    <td>Some text 2</td>
                    <td>Some text 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="Footer">
                    <td>Some text</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </span>

    <div id="ResultListWrapper" class="WidthLimited">
        <table class="ResultListContainer">
            <tbody>
                <tr id="Title">Title here</tr>              
                <tr id="Body">
                    <td>Some text 1</td>
                    <td>Some text 2</td>
                    <td>Some text 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="Body">
                    <td>Some text 1</td>
                    <td>Some text 2</td>
                    <td>Some text 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="Body">
                    <td>Some text 1</td>
                    <td>Some text 2</td>
                    <td>Some text 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="Body">
                    <td>Some text 1</td>
                    <td>Some text 2</td>
                    <td>Some text 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="Body">
                    <td>Some text 1</td>
                    <td>Some text 2</td>
                    <td>Some text 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="Footer">
                    <td>Some text</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also got the following JavaScript to be able to adjust the width:

```
function fn_wrapperResultList()
{
    var wObj = document.getElementById("ResultListWrapper");
    var pObj = document.getElementById("SearchControl");

    if(window.attachEvent) 
    {                
        if(pObj.offsetWidth>wObj.offsetWidth)
        {
            wObj.style.width=pObj.offsetWidth; 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        wObj.style.width='100%'; 
    }
}
```

In essence what I am trying to accomplish is to adjust the width of my ResultList (which in this case is wider than my SearchControl) and match the width of the SearchControl when the former's width is higher than the latter's width (ResultList.width > SearchControl.width then adjust it).

If I assign a fixed width to my WidthLimited class, my control does change and scroll-x is displayed with no problem and works as expected but I am trying to make it change according to SearchControl.

I've tried lots of things: calculating the width using the getComputedStyle and assigning it to wObj.style.width in that JavaScript code which it does change when but still does not resizes. I added the `display:inline-block;` to the `.WidthLimited` class and nothing. I read that span does not really have a specific width but changing that piece is not really an option at this point.

Is there a way to accomplish what I intend?

Comment: There are many mistakes in your code. some of them are: you are enclosing a div like this: `<div id="Content1"/>`. (_I am 99% sure this is wrong_). and you are calling a id which doesn't exist in javascript which is "_wrapperResultList_". I think you are actually trying to call "_ResultListWrapper_". and the third mistake is you are not calling the defined function anywhere..

Comment: Offtopic, but also not good is giving every `<tr>` the same `id`. An id should be unique, otherwise use a class.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I just created that code to show what I am trying to accomplish. I did had some mistakes I changed in the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CsYVE/22/) @chopper provided below and did not applied them here. I have done so. But those details you guys pointed out in the code the system has the tags close appropriately. The real issue is trying to limit the width of resultListWrapper to my searchControl when resultListWrapper.width > searchControl.width which haven't made it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Chopper I made changes to your initial [jsFiddle] (http://jsfiddle.net/CsYVE/35/) and luckily it is working now! The resulting script looks like this:

```
var searchControl = $('#SearchControl'); 
var resultList = $('#ResultListWrapper'); 

if (resultList.width() > searchControl.width()) 
    resultList.width(searchControl.width());
```

This works in IE9, Chrome, FF and Opera with no issues

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CsYVE/). Is that what you are after?

```
var searchControl = $('#SearchControl');
var resultList = $('#ResultListContainer');
if (searchControl.width() > resultList.width())
    resultList.width(searchControl.width());
```

If you're not familiar with jQuery, have a look [here](http://learn.jquery.com/). Ideally you should do your layout in CSS and only resort to javascript when really necessary. If you could be a bit more specific about what exactly you are trying to do we could help you find a CSS-based solution. Also you should pay attention to the difference between `id` and `class`attributes. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp) for an overview. I hope that helps.

Comment: THanks @chopper. I changed your [jsFiddle.cs](http://jsfiddle.net/CsYVE/22/) like this to make it a little bit more clearer at least I hope. I did find an error on my id/class tag thanks for pointing it out. From your script I changed it since I want to change the width on my resultlist only when this is > than the search control width. I also noticed that you changed my span tag to div so changed it back to span and on the css for the searchControl I specified the width to 50% so you can see the width of the resultList not being limited but instead it spreads to all the way to the right.

Comment: I made changes to your initial [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CsYVE/35/) and luckily it is working now! The resulting script looks like this:

    var searchControl = $('#SearchControl');
    var resultList = $('#ResultListWrapper');
    if (resultList.width() > searchControl.width())
        resultList.width(searchControl.width());

Comment: Great. If that helped, do you mind marking the question as answered?